# Combine a string with a variable to use as a key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some JSON data which looks like this:

```
var products = {
    "prod_1": {
      "name": "Apple",
      "price": "10",
    },

    "prod_2": {
      "name": "Pear",
      "price": 9
    },

    "prod_3": {
      "name": "Grapes",
      "price": 15
    }
}
```

I have a variable called `SelectedProduct` which is equal to either `prod_1`, `prod_2` or `prod_3`.

I want to create a new variable which is equal to the `name` string of the `SelectedProduct`.

So for example
when `SelectedProduct = prod_1`,  `name` should equal `Apple` and
when `SelectedProduct = prod_2`,  `name` should equal `Pear`

I have tried to create a create a new variable that is a string and a variable like this:

```
  var name= 'products.'+SelectedProduct'+'.colour';
```

This however simply creates a variable with the textual content of the variable name.

Is there a way in javascript that I can combine a string with a variable?

Comment: Something like: `products[selectedProduct].name`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
var products = {
    "prod_1": {
      "name": "Apple",
      "price": "10",
    },

    "prod_2": {
      "name": "Pear",
      "price": 9
    },

    "prod_3": {
      "name": "Grapes",
      "price": 15
    }
}
var SelectedProduct = "prod_1"
var SelectedProductName = products[SelectedProduct].name
console.log("The selected product is " + SelectedProductName)
```